# How to change a text in specific subsection into italic?

Tags: latex

Please, help me to change a text (in textmaker - latex) in a specific subsection into italic. However, I want the other subsections remain bold, etc (original setting).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
{\normalfont\itshape ...}
```

to switch the temporarily.